# Preventing SoftMax of VGG on ImageNet in Tensorflow from saturating

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, imagenet

I am working on evaluating the trained model on **VGG_16** [SLIM](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) Tensorflow framework for flowers(ImageNet Dataset)

My Data is RGB in range uint8 (0,255). During preprocessing stage the framework aligns the data along the 0 mean and converts it to float32 format. I see that upon training the logits appear to be very large value which is saturating my softmax as below

```py
network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn(
        "vgg_16",
        num_classes=5,
        is_training=False)

    logits, _ = network_fn(img)

    op_prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits)


# Logits : [[  8.76755524  95.47770691  -5.89457178 -23.20689011 -70.85565948]]
```

One solution I tried was to [subtract the absolute logits by the max value](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:Softmax_Regression), but that did not solve the problem as the range for these logits appear unusual.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. ?